# Finding a div tab in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm currently trying to find this tab and click on it. I'm trying to find a easier way of clicking on this button. In my code, I tried to use find command and it's unable to find this tab.

```
<div role="tab" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true" class="ant-tabs-tab-active ant-tabs-tab">Animals</div>
```

Code:

```
find('tab[div=Animals]').click
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to study CSS selectors a bit more. 'Animals' is text content and CSS does not provide a way to query on text content. In Capybara you can use the `text` option to filter matching nodes by their text content so combining valid CSS with the `text` filter like

```
find('div[role="tab"]', text: 'Animals').click
```

or

```
find('div.ant-tabs-tab', text: 'Animals').click
```

would be ways of clicking on that element

Note: I would recommend https://flukeout.github.io/ to learn what you can and can't do with CSS selectors.